# Differentiating between different values with a Line.Contains()

Tags: c#, string, split, streamreader

Something I was curious about, I'm coding a utility for a old game that I play and this allows for custom NPC's. Long story short, I'm coding a reader for these custom NPC files. I've gotten most of the reading down with a line.contains() method (all code will be shown later) but there's a problem. The file can contain either just "height" or "gfxheight" which both do different things. Using line.contains("width") will make it output both width and gfxwidth twice. I don't really know any good way to explain it so here's the file:

```
width=32
height=32
gfxwidth=64
gfxheight=32
nofireball=1
noiceball=1
noyoshi=1
grabside=0
```

The Console output when I read it in and do what I need to split the lines and such:

[image]

And here's the code I use for height and gfxheight (of course there are others but these are the only problems I have when reading):

```
if (line.Contains("height"))
                    {
                            var split = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                            decimal dc;
                            //var val = int.Parse(split.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine(split[0].ToString() + " is equal to " + split[1].ToString());
                            npcHeight.Value = Decimal.Parse(split[1].ToString());
                            npcHeight.Enabled = true;
                            npcHCb.Checked = true;
                    }

                    if (line.Contains("gfxheight"))
                    {
                        var split = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                        //var val = int.Parse(split.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(split[0].ToString() + " is equal to " + split[1].ToString());
                    }
```

Of course there's also the code for width and gfxwidth and the other various codes but I'm not going to bother posting those because I can apply what I get for the height to those.
So what would I have to do to differentiate between them? Suggestions?

Thanks in advanced,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Read the file into a string array, then parse it into a dictionary.

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines(yourFile);

var config = (from line in file
              let s = line.Split('=')
              select new { Key = s[0], Value = s[1] })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Now you can access anything you want by referencing the key:

```
var gfxHeight = config["gfxheight"];  // gfxHeight is a string containing "32"
```

---

If you know the value after the `=` is *always* a number, you could parse it:

```
var config = (from line in file
              let s = line.Split('=')
              select new { Key = s[0], Value = int.Parse(s[1]) })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var gfxHeight = config["gfxheight"];  // gfxHeight is an int containing 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to figure out what each line is before splitting it, try splitting it first. This parsing approach leverages the *format* of the file and has a much-reduced dependency on its *data*:

```
foreach (var line in lines) {
    var data = line.Split('=', 2);
    if (data.Length != 2) {
        continue;
    }

    var attrib = data[0];
    var value = data[1];
    Console.WriteLine(attrib + " is equal to " + value);

    switch (attrib) {
    case "height":
        // ...
        break;
    case "gfxheight":
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'll experiment with this a bit too; thank you! Might be a bit faster than my method too..haha

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution actually! Be warned: I haven't refreshed the page yet to see any proposed answers.

```
if (line.Contains("width"))
                    {
                            if (line.Contains("gfx"))
                            {
                                var split = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                                //var val = int.Parse(split.ToString());
                                Console.WriteLine(split[0].ToString() + " is equal to " + split[1].ToString());
                                npcWidth.Value = Decimal.Parse(split[1].ToString());
                                npcWidth.Enabled = true;
                                npcWCb.Checked = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var split = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                                Console.WriteLine(split[0].ToString() + " is equal to " + split[1].ToString());
                                pNpcWidth.Value = Decimal.Parse(split[1].ToString());
                                pNpcWidth.Enabled = true;
                                pNpcWidthCb.Checked = true;
                            }
                    }
```

Basically that ^

What it does is checks if the line is width with that line.Contains method. And if it does, it then checks to see if it contains gfx in it (as in gfxheight, gfxwidth, etc) and if it does, then that's the gfxheight or gfxwidth value. If not, it's the regular height/width.